# Last element class name is not outputting in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML

```
<ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/mysite/">HOME</a></li>
<li class="item-102"><a href="/mysite/index.php/about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li class="item-103"><a href="/mysite/index.php/products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
<li class="item-104"><a href="/mysite/index.php/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery-

```
 if( jQuery("ul.nav.menu > li").is(':last-child') ) {
    var classes = jQuery(this).attr('class');
    alert(classes);
     //expected output - item-104
     //getting undefined
    }
```

Expected output - **item-104**

Current output - **undefined**

Let me know what I am doing wrong :(

Fiddle - [http://jsfiddle.net/mPHLz/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/mPHLz/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to window, the global scope, not an HtmlElement.

Try this:

```
jQuery(jQuery("ul.nav.menu > li:last-child")).attr('class');
```

Also note that this `jQuery("ul.nav.menu > li").is(':last-child')` will always return true as long as you have an `li` in the nav menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (jQuery("ul.nav.menu > li").is(':last-child')) {
    var classes = jQuery("ul.nav.menu > li:last").attr('class');
    alert(classes);
}
```

`this` refers to the element in the current scope not the `last-child li`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastChild = jQuery("ul.nav.menu > li:last-child");

if (lastChild != null)
{
    var classes = lastChild.attr('class');
    alert(classes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("ul.nav.menu li").each(function() {
if( jQuery(this).is(':last-child') ) {
        var classes = jQuery(this).attr('class');
        alert(classes);
        }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPHLz/8/

Answer (score 0):

Because the this is pointing to the window object or some other element. The if statement does not magically change the scope of this like the callbacks do in `each()`. Just create a selector that grabs the last element and than read its class.

```
var lastElem = jQuery("ul.nav.menu > li:last-child");
var classes = lastElem.attr('class');
console.log(classes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var classes = $("ul.nav.menu > li ").filter(":last-child").attr('class');
alert(classes);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPHLz/12/